# How to get a button if i know it's code

Tags: 16.04

I have a problem with my keyboard or something. There is a button that is always "on". I have just it's code 0xdd and i need somehow to find out what this button is, to turn it off. Moreover 0xdd doesen't type anything at all.
I have Lenovo Flex 2-15

Answer (score 0):

0xdd = 221

According to the HID tables its Keypad Hexadecimal.

http://www.usb.org/developers/hidpage/Hut1_12v2.pdf